# How can I switch between acts?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I visit previous acts?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66676/how-do-i-visit-previous-acts)

If I'm in ACT II for example, and I want to visit ACT I, Do I need to logout to change the quest? Or is there a way to do it inside the game?

Comment: assuming that there is no other way then?